# Generating sinusoidal music as WAV output in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, node.js, ecmascript-6, music

This is a single isomorphic `class` in ES6, written with the intention of generating a full WAV file given note names and durations in seconds. In JavaScript it can be exported as a `Blob` and in Node.js it can be exported as a `Buffer`, to be written to the filesystem.

I have left thorough comments in the code to help document the usage of the function arguments. There is also an example script at the end utilizing this small library.

I hope to address readability and/or performance, but any other advice is welcome too.

```
class WAV {
  static frequency(note) {
    const map = {
      'REST': 0,
      'A0': 27.5,
      'A0#': 29.135,
      'B0b': 29.135,
      'B0': 30.868,
      'C1b': 30.868,
      'C1': 32.703,
      'C1#': 34.648,
      'D1b': 34.648,
      'D1': 36.708,
      // ...
      // skipped for brevity
      // ...
      'C8': 4185.984
    };

    return map[note];
  }

  constructor(numChannels = 1, sampleRate = 44100, data = [], bitsPerSample = 16, littleEndian = true) {
    // WAV header is always 44 bytes
    this.header = new ArrayBuffer(44);
    // flexible container for reading / writing raw bytes in header
    this.view = new DataView(this.header);
    // leave sound data as non typed array for more flexibility
    this.data = data;

    // initialize as non-configurable because it
    // causes script to freeze when using parsed
    // chunk sizes with wrong endianess assumed
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'littleEndian', {
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: true,
      value: littleEndian,
      writable: false
    });

    // initial write index in data array
    this.pointer = 0;

    // WAV header properties
    this.ChunkID = littleEndian ? 'RIFF' : 'RIFX';
    this.ChunkSize = this.header.byteLength - 8;
    this.Format = 'WAVE';
    this.SubChunk1ID = 'fmt ';
    this.SubChunk1Size = 16;
    this.AudioFormat = 1;
    this.NumChannels = numChannels;
    this.SampleRate = sampleRate;
    this.ByteRate = numChannels * sampleRate * bitsPerSample >>> 3;
    this.BlockAlign = numChannels * bitsPerSample >>> 3;
    this.BitsPerSample = bitsPerSample
    this.SubChunk2ID = 'data';
    this.SubChunk2Size = data.length * bitsPerSample >>> 3;
  }

  // internal setter for writing strings as raw bytes to header
  setString(str, byteLength = str.length, byteOffset = 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < byteLength; i++) {
      this.view.setUint8(byteOffset + i, str.charCodeAt(i));
    }
  }

  // internal getter for reading raw bytes as strings from header
  getString(byteLength, byteOffset = 0) {
    for (var i = 0, str = ''; i < byteLength; i++) {
      str += String.fromCharCode(this.view.getUint8(byteOffset + i));
    }

    return str;
  }

  // header property mutators

  set ChunkID(str) {
    this.setString(str, 4, 0);
  }

  get ChunkID() {
    return this.getString(4, 0);
  }

  set ChunkSize(uint) {
    this.view.setUint32(4, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get ChunkSize() {
    return this.view.getUint32(4, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set Format(str) {
    this.setString(str, 4, 8);
  }

  get Format() {
    return this.getString(4, 8);
  }

  set SubChunk1ID(str) {
    this.setString(str, 4, 12);
  }

  get SubChunk1ID() {
    return this.getString(4, 12);
  }

  set SubChunk1Size(uint) {
    this.view.setUint32(16, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get SubChunk1Size() {
    return this.view.getUint32(16, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set AudioFormat(uint) {
    this.view.setUint16(20, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get AudioFormat() {
    return this.view.getUint16(20, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set NumChannels(uint) {
    this.view.setUint16(22, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get NumChannels() {
    return this.view.getUint16(22, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set SampleRate(uint) {
    this.view.setUint32(24, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get SampleRate() {
    return this.view.getUint32(24, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set ByteRate(uint) {
    this.view.setUint32(28, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get ByteRate() {
    return this.view.getUint32(28, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set BlockAlign(uint) {
    this.view.setUint16(32, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get BlockAlign() {
    return this.view.getUint16(32, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set BitsPerSample(uint) {
    this.view.setUint16(34, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get BitsPerSample() {
    return this.view.getUint16(34, this.littleEndian);
  }

  set SubChunk2ID(str) {
    this.setString(str, 4, 36);
  }

  get SubChunk2ID() {
    return this.getString(4, 36);
  }

  set SubChunk2Size(uint) {
    this.view.setUint32(40, uint, this.littleEndian);
  }

  get SubChunk2Size() {
    return this.view.getUint32(40, this.littleEndian);
  }

  // internal getter for sound data as
  // typed array based on header properties
  get typedData() {
    var bytesPerSample = this.BitsPerSample >>> 3;
    var data = this.data;
    var size = this.SubChunk2Size;
    var bytes = size / bytesPerSample;
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(size);
    var dataView = new DataView(buffer);

    // convert signed normalized sound data to typed integer data
    // i.e. [-1, 1] -> [INT_MIN, INT_MAX]
    var amplitude = (1 << ((bytesPerSample << 3) - 1)) - 1;
    var i;

    switch (bytesPerSample) {
    case 1:
      for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        // convert signed to unsigned by adding 128
        // WAV uses unsigned data for 8-bit encoding
        dataView.setUint8(i, data[i] * amplitude + 128);
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        dataView.setInt16(i * 2, data[i] * amplitude, this.littleEndian);
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
        dataView.setInt32(i * 4, data[i] * amplitude, this.littleEndian);
      }
    }

    return buffer;
  }

  // binary container outputs

  // browser-specific
  // generates blob from concatenated typed arrays
  toBlob() {
    return new Blob([this.header, this.typedData], {type: 'audio/wav'});
  }

  // Node.js-specific
  // generates buffer from concatenated typed arrays
  toBuffer() {
    return Buffer.concat([Buffer.from(this.header), Buffer.from(this.typedData)]);
  }

  // sound data mutators

  // writes the specified note to the sound data
  // for amount of time in seconds
  // at given normalized amplitude
  // to channels listed (or all by default)
  // adds to existing data by default
  // and does not reset write index after operation by default
  addNote(note, time, amplitude = 1, channels = [], blend = true, reset = false) {
    var i;

    // by default write to all channels
    if (channels.length === 0) {
      channels = new Array(this.NumChannels);

      for (i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
        channels[i] = i;
      }
    }

    // creating local references to properties
    var data = this.data;
    var numChannels = this.NumChannels;
    var sampleRate = this.SampleRate;
    var bitsPerSample = this.BitsPerSample;

    // calculating properties of given note
    var frequency = WAV.frequency(note) * Math.PI * 2 / sampleRate;
    var period = Math.PI * 2 / frequency;

    // amount of blocks to be written
    var samplesOut = Math.round(sampleRate * time);
    // reduces sound artifacts by stopping at last block
    // where sine wave is approximately 0
    var nonZero = Math.round(samplesOut / period) * period;

    // index of start and stop samples
    var start = this.pointer;
    var stop = data.length;

    // determines amount of blocks to be updated
    var samplesIn = Math.min(Math.floor((stop - start) / numChannels), samplesOut);

    // i = index of each sample block
    i = 0;
    // j = index of each channel in block
    var j;

    // update existing data
    if (blend && frequency > 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < samplesIn; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < channels.length; j++) {
          data[start + i * numChannels + channels[j]] += amplitude * (
            i > nonZero ? 0 : Math.sin(frequency * i)
          );
        }
      }
    } else if (blend) {
      i = samplesIn;
    }

    // append or overwrite data
    for (; i < samplesOut; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < numChannels; j++) {
        data[start + i * numChannels + j] = amplitude * (
          frequency === 0 || i > nonZero || channels.indexOf(j) === -1 ?
          0 : Math.sin(frequency * i)
        );
      }
    }

    // update header properties
    var end = Math.max(start + samplesOut * numChannels, stop) * bitsPerSample >>> 3;

    this.ChunkSize = end + this.header.byteLength - 8;
    this.SubChunk2Size = end;

    if (!reset) {
      // move write index to end of written data
      this.pointer = start + i * numChannels;
    }
  }

  // adds specified notes in series
  // each playing for time * relativeDuration seconds
  // followed by a time * (1 - relativeDuration) second rest
  addProgression(notes, times, amplitude = 1, channels = [], blend = true, reset = false, relativeDuration = 1) {
    var start = this.pointer;

    for (var i = 0, note, time, rest; i < notes.length; i++) {
      note = notes[i];

      if (relativeDuration === 1 || WAV.frequency(note) === 0) {
        this.addNote(note, times[i], amplitude, channels, blend, false);
      } else {
        time = times[i] * relativeDuration;
        rest = times[i] - time;

        this.addNote(note, time, amplitude, channels, blend, false);
        this.addNote('REST', rest, amplitude, channels, blend, false);
      }
    }

    if (reset) {
      this.pointer = start;
    }
  }

  // adds specified notes in parallel
  // playing for time * relativeDuration seconds
  // followed by a time * (1 - relativeDuration) second rest
  addChord(notes, time, amplitude = 1 / notes.length, channels = [], blend = true, reset = false, relativeDuration = 1) {
    var start = this.pointer;

    var secs = time * relativeDuration;
    var rest = time - secs;

    for (var i = 0, note; i < notes.length; i++) {
      // reset pointer manually at the beginning of each iteration
      this.pointer = start;

      note = notes[i];

      if (relativeDuration === 1 || WAV.frequency(note) === 0) {
        this.addNote(note, time, amplitude, channels, blend, false);
      } else {
        this.addNote(note, secs, amplitude, channels, blend, false);
        this.addNote('REST', rest, amplitude, channels, blend, false);
      }

      // after 1st iteration, notes must blend since they are in parallel
      blend = true;
    }

    if (reset) {
      this.pointer = start;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Example Usage

```js
/* song data for Portal - Still Alive */
var S = 0.125, // sixteenth note
    E = 0.25,  // eighth note
    Q = 0.5,   // quarter note
    H = 1,     // half note
    W = 2;     // whole note

    // primary melody notes (channel 0)
var melody = ["G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "REST", "A4", "G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "A4", "E5", "F5#", "G5", "E5", "C5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "A4", "F5#", "REST", "G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "REST", "A4", "G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "REST", "E5", "F5#", "G5", "E5", "C5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "D5", "E5", "F5", "E5", "D5", "C5", "REST", "A4", "A4#", "C5", "F5", "E5", "D5", "D5", "C5", "D5", "C5", "C5", "C5", "A4", "A4#", "C5", "F5", "G5", "F5", "E5", "D5", "D5", "E5", "F5", "F5", "G5", "A5", "A5#", "A5#", "A5", "G5", "F5", "G5", "A5", "A5", "G5", "F5", "D5", "C5", "D5", "F5", "F5", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "F5#", "A5", "D6", "F6#", "D6", "B5", "D6", "F6#", "D6", "A5", "D6", "F6#", "D6", "B5", "D6", "F6#", "D6", "A5", "D6", "F6#", "D6", "B5", "D6", "F6#", "D6", "REST", "A4", "G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "REST", "G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "REST", "E5", "F5#", "G5", "E5", "C5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "A4", "F5#", "REST", "A4", "G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "REST", "A4", "G5", "F5#", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "REST", "E5", "F5#", "G5", "E5", "C5#", "D5", "E5", "A4", "D5", "E5", "F5", "E5", "D5", "C5", "A4", "A4#", "C5", "F5", "E5", "D5", "D5", "C5", "D5", "C5", "C5", "C5", "A4", "A4#", "C5", "F5", "G5", "F5", "E5", "D5", "D5", "E5", "F5", "F5", "G5", "A5", "A5#", "A5#", "A5", "G5", "F5", "G5", "A5", "A5", "G5", "F5", "F5", "D5", "C5", "D5", "F5", "F5", "E5", "E5", "F5#", "F5#", "REST", "A5", "A5", "B5", "A5", "F5#", "D5", "E5", "F5#", "F5#", "REST", "G5", "A5", "A5", "REST", "G5", "F5#", "F5#", "REST"],
    // secondary melody notes (channel 0)
    melody_sec = ["REST", "B5", "A5", "G5", "G5", "A5", "REST", "B5", "A5", "G5", "G5", "A5", "F5#", "G5", "D5", "REST", "G5", "A5", "A5"],
    // primary harmony notes (channel 1)
    harmony = ["REST", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "B3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "B3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3#", "D4", "F4", "A4", "REST", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "B3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "E4", "G4", "E4", "A3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "B3", "D4", "F4#", "D4", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "E4", "E4", "E4", "F4#", "G4", "A3", "A3", "A3", "B3", "C4#", "A3", "A3#", "A3#", "A3#", "A3#", "A3#", "A3#", "A3#", "F4", "F4", "REST", "C4", "C4", "REST", "A3#", "A3#", "REST", "F4", "F4", "REST", "F4", "F4", "REST", "C4", "C4", "REST", "A3#", "A3#", "REST", "F4", "F4", "REST", "A3#", "A3#", "A3#", "A3#", "C4", "C4", "C4", "C4", "F4", "F4", "E4", "E4", "D4", "D4", "C4", "C4", "A3#", "F4", "A3", "E4", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "D4", "B3", "B3", "D4", "REST"],
    // secondary harmony notes (channel 1)
    harmony_sec = ["REST", "C4", "C4", "REST", "G3", "G3", "REST", "F3", "F3", "REST", "C4", "C4", "REST", "C4", "C4", "REST", "G3", "G3", "REST", "F3", "F3", "REST", "C4", "C4", "REST", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "G3", "C4", "C4", "B3", "B3", "A3", "A3", "G3", "G3"];
    // primary melody durations (channel 0)
var melody_durs = [E, E, E, E, H, W - E, E, E, E, E, Q, Q + E, Q, E, W, E, Q, E, Q + E, E, Q, Q + E, Q, E, Q, W - E, H, E, E, E, E, H, W - E, E, E, E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, H + E, H, Q, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, E, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q + E, E, E, E, E, E + S, H - S, W, E, E, E, Q + E, E, Q, Q, H + E, H, Q, E, Q + E, Q, Q, E, Q + E, E, Q, H + E, H + E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, W + E, E, E, E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, H + E, H, Q, E, Q + E, Q, Q, E, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q + E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, E, E, E, E, E, Q, E, E, H + Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, E, E, Q + E, Q + E, E, E, Q + E, Q + E, E, E, H + E, H],
    // secondary melody durations (channel 0)
    melody_sec_durs = [34 * W, E, E, E, E, Q, W + Q, E, E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, H + E, 12 * W + E, E, E, Q + E],
    // primary harmony durations (channel 1)
    harmony_durs = [H, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, 7 * W + H, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, E, E, Q, Q + E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, Q + E, E, H, H],
    // secondary harmony durations (channel 1)
    harmony_sec_durs = [41 * W + H, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, Q, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E, E];
/* end song data */

// construct an instance of WAV with
// 2 channels
// sample rate of 44100 samples/second
// no initial data
// 16 bits per sample
// little endian byte order
var wav = new WAV(2, 44100, [], 16, true);

// add each layer of song as a progression

// add primary melody with
// normalized amplitude of 0.6
// to channel 0
// without blending
// reset internal pointer
// relative duration of 0.75
wav.addProgression(melody, melody_durs, 0.6, [0], false, true, 0.75);

// add secondary melody with
// normalized amplitude of 0.4
// to channel 0
// with blending
wav.addProgression(melody_sec, melody_sec_durs, 0.4, [0], true, true, 0.75);

// add primary harmony with
// normalized amplitude of 0.6
// to channel 1
wav.addProgression(harmony, harmony_durs, 0.6, [1], true, true, 0.75);

// add secondary harmony with
// normalized amplitude of 0.4
wav.addProgression(harmony_sec, harmony_sec_durs, 0.4, [1], true, true, 0.75);

// create chunk of memory containing WAV header and sound data
var blob = wav.toBlob();
// create temporary local URL from generated blob
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// create audio source from URL
var audio = new Audio(url);
// play the created audio
audio.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/patrickroberts/3b065ab94ce5094baacf45ed23e2a16e/raw/0b2592af2af4d271a4fc659e5f291d1b3ba1a952/wav.babel.js"></script>
```

Comment: @wOxxOm I was looking at the documentation for the closure compiler just now. It appears not to be a good solution for projects that are intended to be used as libraries, but rather a solution for complete, self-contained applications, so I don't think compiling my code applies in this case.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612 I'm sorry, I didn't realize that was not acceptable. I thought that leaving the original question intact would make the revision legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any performance optimization must start with Timeline/JS profiling.

In this case the slowest part is `typedData` getter, ~850ms on i7 CPU with the OP's example. This is an enormously huge time for such a simple operation.

Let's speed it up 10 times or more by eliminating function calls to DataView's methods in favor of directly accessed unsigned byte view:

```
var uint8 = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

8-bit WAV case is simple:

```
case 1:
  for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
    uint8[i] = data[i] * amplitude + 128;
  }
  break;
```

16-bit WAV requires us to implement byte order maintenance manually (see P.S.):

```
case 2:
  if (this.littleEndian) {
    for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
      var v = data[i] * amplitude;
      if (!v) {
        uint8[i * 2] = 0;
        uint8[i * 2 + 1] = 0;
      } else {
        if (v < 0) {
          v = 65536 + v;
        }
        uint8[i * 2] = v & 255;
        uint8[i * 2 + 1] = v >> 8;
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
      var v = data[i] * amplitude;
      if (!v) {
        uint8[i * 2] = 0;
        uint8[i * 2 + 1] = 0;
      } else {
        if (v < 0) {
          v = 65536 + v;
        }
        uint8[i * 2] = v >> 8;
        uint8[i * 2 + 1] = v & 255;
      }
    }
  }
  break;
```

32-bit case is similar.

Eliminate the largest bottlenecks and repeat the profiling tests progressively until satisfied.

P.S. The optimized 16-bit case without inner-loop branching as per the comments:

```
case 2:
  if (this.littleEndian) {
    for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
      var v = (data[i] * amplitude + 65536) & 65535;
      uint8[i * 2] = v & 255;
      uint8[i * 2 + 1] = v >> 8;
    }
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
      var v = (data[i] * amplitude + 65536) & 65535;
      uint8[i * 2] = v >> 8;
      uint8[i * 2 + 1] = v & 255;
    }
  }
  break;
```

Comment: I've read content from stackoverflow claiming that `DataView` methods for manually determining endianess were slow, and now I understand why. I will definitely use this advice, thank you. If you don't mind me asking, is there a reason the `if (!v)` check is necessary? It seems to be unnecessary branching logic within a heavy `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite probably an unnecessary comparison. A leftover from my initial experiments. Such preemptive microoptimizations aren't needed usually.

Comment: By the way, I noticed a semantic issue with the variable name `bytes`. I should have called it `samples`. So, thanks for helping me notice that.

Comment: Try `var v = (data[i] * amplitude + 65536) & 65535;` without both inner `if` checks.

Comment: Already figured that out on my own. I'm gonna update my question with my iterated refactors based on your advice.

Comment: I thought the questions should not be altered as per the rules.

Comment: I just saw this reply, if I don't get anymore answers for a few days, I will mark yours as accepted, and also post my own answer outlining the improvements I've made.